# Javascript - Separating links depending of if link belongs to image

Tags: javascript

I am trying to separate links based on if a specific link belongs to an image. What I have so far:

```
//get all links
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
//get all image_links
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

var all_links = [];
var all_images = [];
var text_links = [];

for (var l = 0;l < links.length; l++) {
all_links.push(links[l]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
all_images.push(images[i].parentNode.href);
}
```

How can I add I create a new array (`text_links`) which contains all links that are NOT contained in the `all_images` array? So essentially Im attempting to:

1. Finding all links.
2. Finding all image links.
3. Filtering out links that are not contained in the image_links array into the text_links array.

Is the a better way to get this done using pure JS or do I have to use a library?

HTML for image link(taking the href for the parentNode):

```
<a title="Cooling Solutions" href="http://www.url.com/" onclick="s_objectID="http://www.url.com/?povid=P1171-C1143.2978+1139.3124-L0_1";return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">
<img width="495" height="225" src="http://i3.url.com/images/Site495x225.png" usemap="#map-33">
</a>
```

Comment: How does a link belonging to an image look like? Or do you mean links containing an image, since `img` can't have HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the update, now it makes more sense. So, you need the `href` from `a` to be added to `text_links`, but not `href`s within `area`s?

Comment: Yes, Im trying to separate href's that are the parentNodes to an image tag.

Comment: OK, but do you want to include `href`s within `area`s to `text_links`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you are going to want something like this... I have not tried it, but its going to be close to this.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var textLinksArray = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if(links[i].innerHTML.match( /\bimg\b/ )) {
        alert(links[i]);
    } else {
        textLinksArray.push(links[i]);
    }
}

//text links array only contains links without images.
```

### edited for keeping track of links sans img tags

Comment: for( i = 0; links.length; i++ ) causes an infinite loop and an implicit global, and the regexp misses uppercase tag HTML...

Comment: @dandavis thanks, yeah turns out them loops sometimes need a comparison.

Comment: @recneps This excludes also a text link which has a word `img` in the text.